# Fill the file details when dropped into input file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have made a drag and drop file upload. Now when a file is dropped in the drop zone it should fill the data of the dropped file into `<input type="file">`. How to do it ?

**HTML**
:

```
<div id='slct'>
  Select file <input type="file" id="filename"
                onchange="readURL(this);" /> <input type="button" value="Upload"
                onclick="sendFile()" /><br> Or
</div>
<button id='uploadDrp'>Upload</button>
<div class="drop">
<div id="filedrag">drop file here</div>
<img src="#" id="prof">
</div>
```

**JavaScript :**

```
   obj.on("dragover", function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).css("border", "1px solid #00aaff");
    });
    obj.on("drop", function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).css("border", "1px solid #00aaff");
        $("#slct").hide();
        $("#uploadDrp").fadeIn(500);
        var dt = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
        file01 = dt;
        var files = dt.files;
        if (dt.files.length > 0) {
            if (dt.files && dt.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    $('#prof').attr('src', e.target.result).width(200)
                            .height(200);
                    $('#prof').fadeIn();
                };

                reader.readAsDataURL(dt.files[0]);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: You can't set the value of a file input, due to security restrictions

Comment: Oh... Is there any other way??

Comment: You're getting Base64, so you could either add it to a hidden input or use FormData to submit it

Comment: can u send the code snippet for that as an answer..?

Comment: What does `sendFile()` do, how do you send the file, and where

Comment: that is a method  which will send the uploaded file to server..I send it through arraybuffer

Comment: So you're using ajax? If so you can use FormData and just append the dropped file

Comment: How to append the dropped file..? send me the code snippet..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## History lession

It s like @adeneo said,

> You can't set the value of a file input, due to security restrictions

But in some browser you can set the value to a empty string to clear the field.
In older (IE) browser you need to replace the DOM-node completely

However there is one way to change the input-file-value and that is with another instance of `FileList`
but you do not set the value, instead you set the `input.files` property: see jsfiddle demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/F9PDA/)

I [filled a bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=390457) long ago to ask if we could get access to construct a new FileList
We had it globaly in window but there is no way we can use it...

```
var file1 = new File(['foo'], 'foo.txt')
var file2 = new File(['bar'], 'bar.txt')
new window.FileList([file1, file2]) // throws Illegal constructor
```

There response was that they are moving towards a normal array instead.
It s being descussed [here](https://github.com/w3c/FileAPI/issues/19) to change it. But there is little to no progress in that field...

## Solution

Unfortenly you can not change the value and sumbit the form, Instead you need to create a own FormData and post it using ajax
Then you can redirect to the target url...

```
// Make your own FormData
var fd = new FormData

// Add all drang'n'drop files
for (let file of dt.files) 
  fd.append('files', file)

// Add all input files
for (let file of input.files) 
  fd.append('files', file)

// upload it using xhr or the new fetch api
fetch(targetUrl, {method: 'post', body: fd}).then(redirect)
```

## Code review

```
if (dt.files.length > 0) {
    // it's unnecessary to have two if statement that checks the same thing
    if (dt.files && dt.files[0]) { 
        // Using FileReader is unnecessary and also worse
        // see this performance test: https://jsfiddle.net/fdzmd4mg/1
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            $('#prof').attr('src', e.target.result).width(200).height(200);
            $('#prof').fadeIn();
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(dt.files[0]);
    }
}
```

What i think you should do instead is something like this

```
if (dt.files && dt.files[0]) {
    // store the file list somehere to upload them later
    // window.files = Array.from(dt.files)
    // window.files = [dt.files[0]]

    let url = URL.createObjectURL(dt.files[0])
    $('#prof').attr('src', url).width(200).height(200);
    $('#prof').fadeIn();
}
```